# System Lock after failed login attempts in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, security, ms-access, authentication, block

I use this code for my login form:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim ErrorCount As Integer = 0

    If (ErrorCount = 3) Then
        MessageBox.Show(" The System has been Lock ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Form3.Show()
    Else

        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection( _
                   "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= UserPass.mdb;")
        con.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM UserPass WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", txtPassword.Text)
        Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' It will be case sensitive if you compare usernames here.   
        If sdr.HasRows Then
            If sdr.Read Then
                If txtPassword.Text <> sdr("Password").ToString Or txtUsername.Text <> sdr("Username").ToString Then
                    MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show(" You are now Logged In! ", " Welcome! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                    frmOne.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If


        sdr.Close()
        con.Close()
    End If
```

What im trying to do is when the user fails to login to the system 3 times, the system will show another form that says the system is locked and the user needs to type in the password from the system to be able to try to log-in again. Kindly help please.

im using ms access as database for the username and password

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i've tried this:
Dim errorcount As Integer = 3
Then on the if statement where it checks username and password i added this:
errorcount = errorcount - 1

then created an if statement:
If errorcount = 0 Then
form3.show
end if

but nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of two of the other answers. You need to change the declaration to static so that it maintains state. `Dim ErrorCount As Integer = 0` to  `Static ErrorCount As Integer`

You also need to add a decrement to the code path where the user has entered an invalid username.

```
MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1 'add this here
```

Then move the if so that it is after the SQL so move this to after `con.close()`

```
If (ErrorCount = 3) Then
    MessageBox.Show(" The System has been Lock ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Form3.Show()
Else
```

Also you seem to have some confusion about parameterized queries. If your using parameterized queries then you don't need to concatenate your SQL which should be

```
    str = "SELECT * FROM UserPass WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass"
```

Also the inside if should never be true under normal conditions

```
If txtPassword.Text <> sdr("Password").ToString Or txtUsername.Text <> sdr("Username").ToString Then 
     ' this code path is only evaluated if the database ignores the where clause or 
     ' the user changes the username or password textboxs whilst the database connection is proccessing and is therfore unnessacary 
     MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
     ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
Else
     MessageBox.Show(" You are now Logged In! ", " Welcome! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
     frmOne.Show()
     Me.Hide()
End If
```

Finally don't store passwords as plaintext. Use a hash from the [`System.Security.Cryptography` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) with a salt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand the question. But this part makes it sound to me like you are trying to lock the *computer's entire desktop* after a logon attempt *in your program* has failed three times:

> What im trying to do is when the user fails to login to the system 3 times, the system will show another form that says the system is locked and the user needs to type in the password from the system to be able to try to log-in again.

I'm not sure that's a good idea. Wouldn't it be sufficient just to lock the user out of *your program* instead of locking the entire computer? Think of it like this: there's no reason to inflict a global punishment for a local infraction.

But, putting aside whether or not I think it's a good idea, it's perfectly do-able from VB.NET. All you need to do is call the [`LockWorkStation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875.aspx) function after your counter indicates that three failed login attempts have occurred. This function is provided as part of the Win32 API, so to call it directly from a .NET application, you'll need to use P/Invoke. This function has a relatively simple signature, so its definition shouldn't be too hard to understand either:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=True)> _
Public Shared Function LockWorkStation() As Boolean
End Function
```

This function has some important constraints on its use, namely that it can only be called by processes that are running on the interactive desktop. This is not a problem for you, though, since you're building a GUI application that can only run on the interactive desktop, and you know that if someone has entered an invalid password three times, they're definitely logged in and sitting a few feet from the keyboard.

Invoking the magic from your code is relatively simple, although it's possible for the function to fail and you should handle those error conditions (lest someone find a security backdoor into your application):

```
If (FailedLogonAttempts < 3) Then
    ' Do whatever...
Else
    ' Lock 'em out!
    Dim success As Boolean = LockWorkstation()
    If Not success Then
        ' Uh-oh! An error occurred! You need to handle this, otherwise someone
        ' might be able to gain unauthorized access to the system.
        '
        ' For demonstration and debugging purposes, we'll throw an exception,
        ' but that's obviously not a secure long-term solution.
        Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
    End If
End If
```

---

If you're just asking how to fix your existing code, the problem is that your `ErrorCode` variable never goes beyond 0. You've declared it at the top of the `btnLogin_Click` method like so:

```
Dim ErrorCount As Integer = 0
```

That's as a regular variable with method-level scope. That means it is re-initialized (to 0, like you ask it to be) every time that the method runs and does not retain its value.

If you want to declare a variable with method-level scope that *does* retain its value, you need to declare the variable using the [`Static` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx), like so:

```
Static ErrorCount As Integer = 0
```

A great way to test these things, and figure out what's wrong, is to set a breakpoint inside of the `btnLogin_Check` method and see exactly what values the variables have! If you did that, you'd notice that each time, `ErrorCount` is set to 0 after execution passes over the first line. That would be your immediate clue as to what the problem is. Then you just have to figure out how to make the value stick. Now you know you do it using the `Static` keyword (or moving up a scope, like making it a member of your Form class so that it lives as long as objects of that class).

Comment: The system will only be locked. I run the program in visual studio and i don't plan to lock the whole desktop just the system. When the system is locked, it will only show a Form that has a textbox that requires the user to put in the correct password and the system will be unlocked

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
Dim ErrorCount As Int = 0

If (ErrorCount =3) Then
     MessageBox.Show(" The System has been Lock ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

'Do stuff 
'Add Your Code to show new Form something like
 Me.Hide()
 Form3.Show()


Else 

Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection( _
           "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= UserPass.mdb;")


con.Open()
Dim str As String
str = "SELECT * FROM UserPass WHERE Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", txtUsername.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", txtPassword.Text)
Dim sdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
' It will be case sensitive if you compare usernames here.   
If sdr.HasRows Then
    If sdr.Read Then
        If txtPassword.Text <> sdr("Password").ToString Or txtUsername.Text <> sdr("Username").ToString Then
            MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

             ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1 

        Else
            MessageBox.Show(" You are now Logged In! ", " Welcome! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
            frmOne.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show(" Incorrect Username/Password. Login Denied ", " Error! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If

    sdr.Close()
    con.Close()

End If
```

Best Regards

Comment: i also changed the counter++ to counter = counter + 1 because counter++ is an error

Comment: still doesnt show the form. it also doesnt show the message box that says the system is locked

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Public Class Form1
    Private attempt As Integer = 3

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\testing.Accdb;")
    cn.Open()
    If txtpassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Your Password !!!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Attention...")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader
    Dim com1 As New OleDbCommand

    com1.CommandText = "select [UserID],[Pass] from userinfo where userid = '" & txtUserID.Text & "'"
    com1.Connection = cn
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()
    dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader
    If dr1.Read Then
        If UCase(dr1("Pass")) = UCase(txtpassword.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Welecome")
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password  [" & attempt - 1 & "]  Attempt(s) Remaing")
            attempt -= 1
            txtpassword.Focus()
            If attempt = 0 Then
                End
            End If
        End If
        Exit Sub

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong UserID  [" & attempt - 1 & "]  Attempt(s) Remaing")
        attempt -= 1
        txtpassword.Focus()
        If attempt = 0 Then
            End
        End If
    End If
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This doesn't close the connection on the final attempt